# HTML5 video fails to load after loading few videos

Tags: angularjs, html, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am trying to build a web application that lists videos. I have a problem with internet explorer.

Here is my view

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-12 col-md-6" ng-repeat="video in videos track by $index">
 <video>
   <source ng-src="{{video.url}}" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
</div>
```

I am lazy loading videos on controller side. Each scroll bottom adds 4 new elements to videos.

```
videoFactory.load($scope.videos.length, 4).then(function(res){
     $scope.videos = $scope.videos.concat(res.data.data);
});
```

And everything works fine on all browsers except internet explorer 9 to Edge.

[image: IE Network]

Please look at Internet Explorer network. Everything was fine but suddenly all response headers changed to 206. Video with the name "iPhone_7" was loaded before with the size of 7,04MB but now it is partially loaded with 6,77MB.

This problems starts after 32 videos are loaded succesfully. And the video error code is 4 which is MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED.

[image]

Comment: Seems like a memory management issue. Does this happen on all computers ?

Comment: @KobyDouek Yes, I couldn't find any solution to it yet.